# Auto-delete after a certain date

Tags: soundcloud

I'm looking to use Soundcloud to promote some upcoming events - I'll have a separate sound file promoting each event.  I'd like the soundfiles to auto-delete once the events have happened. Is there a way of setting a Kill Date field so that after a certain date, the sound file will delete.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly use the API to delete these tracks using whatever logic you need, but there's no feature built-in to SoundCloud to do this automatically.

Here is the documentation for the API: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks

You'd have to be authenticated (obviously), and then send a DELETE request to `/tracks/{id}`